# Custom Taxonomy, shows empty value (home page of website)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization, search

I have added records in wp_terms_taxonomy table and wants to show that record in the list item(dropdown like) exists in the form.

As I have added two records in taxonomy table (taxonomy_name = units_category).
Two li tags shown but with empty value.

The code is:

```
$unit_taxonomies = array(
  'units_category'
);

$unit_args = array(
  'orderby'    => 'name', 
  'order'      => 'ASC',
  'hide_empty' => false
);

$unit_terms  = get_terms($unit_taxonomies, $unit_args);

print_r($unit_terms)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are expecting your code to show and what isn't working.

Comment: sir , i need to fetch the record from unit_taxonomy in a list .
This list exist in search field , that works like select html element

Answer (score -1):

If you are using WordPress newer than 4.5.0 get_terms() function is slightly different. Take a look at [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) definition. Second argument is deprecated and everything is passed through first argument.

Comment: Deprecated but not removed. If you look at the function source then the old style will still work.

Comment: yes, Jan Novak(brother) , Andy is saying right

Comment: Yes, he is right, my mistake. You should provide the code where are you creating list items, so we can easier identify where the problem is.